# APPID and CLIENTKEY in ios apps after deploying parse server to AWS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a parse server to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and rewrite my iOS app in AppDelegate.swift. But i only rewrited the ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server so, the APPID and CLIENTKEY is still the same ID and KEYS that are in parse.api.com

It this a correct way to configure my ID and KEYS and server? or do i need to generate a new APPID by myself in this case?

```
    let config = ParseClientConfiguration(block: {
        (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = APP_ID;
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = CLIENT_ID;
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "EC2 DNS"
    });

    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(config)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is fine. With swift 3 its done like this.

```
    // Init Parse
    let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "XXX"
        $0.clientKey = "XXX"
        $0.server = "XXX"
        $0.isLocalDatastoreEnabled = true

    }
    Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my stupid question. I want you to be careful and check that my applicationId and client key is not changed or regenerated by any way. It is the same things that i used before rewriting my parse configuration. Is it really no doubt about that?

Comment: @wwwwwwwwwwwwww it can not change. Whatever you used for your parse-server setup that will be your keys.

Comment: Thank you for your tolerant answer.